# Count wordpress site view

Tags: php, wordpress

I create function to count view of site, I call `add_action('init', 'wp125_adview');` , but is one problem when I'm in dashboard function also count my views, I want that this function count only view in site not in admin panel, maybe are some parameters for `add_action` that it not will cal function from dashboard  ?

Comment: Why not just use Google Analytics?

Comment: I'm learning wordpess, and want learn how to create plugins

Answer (score 0):

I found it's `add_action('wp', 'wp125_adview');` , when I'm in dashboard wordpess not call function `wp125_adview();`